# Not getting specified value of variables, while using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a;
 char c;
 int *A=&a;
 char *C=&c;
 printf("Enter the value of a,c\n");
 scanf("%d,%d",&a,&c);
 printf ("Adress of a,c= %d,%d\n",A,C);
 printf("value of a,c= %d %d\n",a,c);
 return 0;
}
```

**output is:**

> c:\Users\Avinash\Desktop>a.exe
>
> Enter the value of a,c
>
> 12,40
>
> Adress of a,c= 6356740,6356739
>
> value of a,c= 0, 40

Comment: Use %p to print address.

Comment: whatever value I am assigning to variable a, it always gives "0" in output

Comment: `scanf("%d,%d",&a,&c);` --> `scanf("%d, %c",&a,&c);` or `char c;` --> `int c;`

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved@BLUEPIXY and @MayurK

Comment: You never initialized the `a` and `c` variables, so they could have *any* value when your program starts.  A good coding standard is to initialize variables with a value when they are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%c` for scanning `char`. Change

```
 scanf("%d,%d",&a,&c);
```

to

```
 scanf("%d,%c",&a,&c);   //make sure there is only single comma in between the inputs. Nothing else, nothing more.
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the error is in the scanf() format expression '%d' used for reading the character c.  What is happening is this: Note that the address of c is one lower than the address of a (this is expected for variables on the stack).  Assume a character occupies one byte and an integer occupies 4 bytes.  By using '%d' you are telling scanf() that the second pointer points to an integer; therefore it reads the second value as an integer, --padding out the high-order bits with zeros--, and stores the value --in the four bytes-- based at the address of c.  The padding overwrites the low-order bits of a, explaining why the printf() shows its value as 0.

Answer (score 0):

you have some problem with the scanf format and the printf format

```
int a;
    char c;
    int *A = &a;
    char *C = &c;
    printf("Enter the value of a,c\n");
    scanf("%d, %c", &a, &c);  //%c for reading chars
    printf("Adress of a= %p, c= %p\n", A, C);  // printing the address %p
    printf("value of a= %d c= %c\n", a, c);    //%c for printing chars
```

Comment: thanks, 
but the result was same for "%d" and"%p" for printing address, what could be the possible problems, if I keep using '%d' for getting address

Comment: @AvinashKumarShudhanshu what problem are you getting from the code and what do you want to get that you are not getting? please be specific so that i can help. when you use %d for address it convert the address to integer, some compiler will give you warning, gcc -wall -werror.